# Woocommerce Not Sending Emails

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am having no luck at the WordPress forum. They WordPress system emails work fine. Woocommerce emails don't. Hopefully someone here will know what I need to do.

Woocommerce is not sending "New Account" emails to anybody who registers with the site. The registration actually happens, just no email notification. I do have the "send email notification" box checked.

Woocommerce is not sending a "Reset Password" email. When requested, the page on the site displays, "check your email" but the email never arrives.

I have been searching for a solution for 24 hours now. I hope somebody can help.

Thanks